# Saving action bar state

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

In my `Android` application I'm using the `ActionBar`. I want to show users some status using logo placed in the left side of the `ActionBar`. I can do this:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.new_icon);
```

and it works.

The problem is that this state in to persistent. If I change activity `ActionBar` reset itself, so default logo is shown. Is there any way to save state of the `ActionBar` during application runtime?

Comment: Are u using the stock `ActionBar` or the `ActionBarSherlock`?

Comment: @ss1271 I'm using `ActionBarSherlock`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the standar lifecycle callbacks from Activities

In the OnCreate method of your activity try to read the state

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
      if (data!=null)
      {
          ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
          int state = data.getInt("status");
          if (state==1)
               actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_a);
          else
               actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_b);
      }
}
```

And save the state to recovery it later

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle data) {
      super.onSaveInstanceState(data);
      data.putInt(icon_state);
}
```

Comment: I need to create common base class and then it works.